# Why I do not get first row if am using mysqli_fetch_assoc on first and mysqli_fetch_array second time?

Tags: php

I am populating database column names for sorting my query in a sidebar list using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and that page is included on result page where I am using `mysqli_fetch_array()` to populate the table rows, now what the funny thing was on the result page I was getting only 3 rows where my database was having 4 rows, 1 row less, I was debugging entire code and I came accross that I am using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and `mysqli_fetch_array()` for same query, so if I removed `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` it used to return me 4 rows, but why is this so? I didn't got a bit

I thought I'll populate a comma separated names of table in my database and will explode later but after some internet research I came across this `mysqli_data_seek($fetch_results, 0);` and it solved my issue, but why I was getting 1 row less and after using `mysqli_data_seek($fetch_results, 0);` it returned me all rows that is 4 instead of 3? Can anyone explain me?

> P.S Am using excessive eval as I am developing customized systems, but
>   this is not the issue here, it's secure :)

Comment: You can't read the same row twice with neither functions, if that's what you mean :-? Have you considered that there might simply be a bug in your code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I used `$query=mysqli_query(); mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) {results}` than same for populating rows in a dynamic table so `while($throw_results = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {//here i get 1 row less }` but if I remove the first assoc statement or if I use `mysqli_data_seek($fetch_results, 0);` it fetches all rows

Comment: so you mean I use it for 3 times for different purpose and when I while loop on the fourth time it will remove 3 rows from the result and than return me another rows?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario can you get me on chat I'll explain you

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_data_seek() function seeks to an arbitrary result pointer specified by the offset in the result set represented by result. The offset parameter must be between zero and the total number of rows minus one (0..mysqli_num_rows() - 1).

For help you need know more information about your code...

---

http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysqli-data-seek.htm

Comment: get what? you dont understand function?